# How to set router for earch module in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, router

I have 1 zend (v1) application, and 2 module : default + admin

I want when call default module will be set router in `configs/router/default.ini`
and if in module admin do not any thing

I tried using plugin but it doesn't work

in my plugin

```
class Australian_Controller_Plugin_DefaultRouter extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

    public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        $currModule = $request->getModuleName();
        if ($currModule != 'default') {
            return;
        }
        $fontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $router1 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();
        $fontController->getRouter()->removeDefaultRoutes();
        $myRoutes = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/router/default.ini', 'production');
        $router1->addConfig($myRoutes, 'routes');
        $fontController->setRouter($router1);   

    }

}
```

and `/default/Bootstrap.php`

```
protected function _initRoutes() {

    $fontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $fontController->registerPlugin(new Australian_Controller_Plugin_DefaultRouter());

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are adding new router after Routing so Zend already decoded address using old routes. This way you can generate URLs using new routes, but they will not e recognized by Zend. You need to call `$router->route($request);` again to set module/controller/action using new set of routes. 
Sadly this is not working when its called in routeShutdown and has to be added to `preDispatch()`. Sadly I'm quite new to Zend too and still not grasping why it is so.

Code i used:

```
$fontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$router = $fontController->getRouter();
$r = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                '/testnew',
                array(
                    'module' => 'user',
                    'controller' => 'index',
                    'action' => 'myaccount',
        )); 
$router->addRoute('testnew', $r);
$router->route($request);
```